# How to use the Backwards Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

Given the ODE $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(t,y)$ and the function $f(y) = -y^3$, with the initial condition $y(0)=1$, I want to use the backward Euler Method with $h = \frac{1}{2}$, combined with the Newton-Rapson method to approximate $y$ at $t = 2$.

This ODE is seperable and an exact solution can be found, which I found to be $y = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2t+1}}.$
Therefore at $t = 2$ the exact solution would be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}$.

However, I want to know how to use these two numerical methods to approximate a solution. So far, I used the Backward Euler Method as follows:

$$y_{n+1} \approx y_n + hf(t_{n+1}, y_{n+1})$$
$$y_{n+1} \approx 1 - \frac{1}{2}y_{n+1}^3$$

This forms the cubic equation $y_{n+1}^3 + 2y_{n+1} - 2 \approx 0$ which can be solved via Newton-Raphson, and this gives me a value of $y_{n+1} = 0.7709$. But where can I go from here? Have I made a mistake? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You know $t_0=0$ and $y_0 = 1$. And with even spaced points $t_k = hk$ you know that $t_4=2$ when $h=1/2$. So you need to use $y_{n+1} = y_n - hy_{n+1}^3$ to recursively compute $y_1,y_2,y_3$ and then finally $y_4$. What you have computed is just $y_1$, i.e. $y(1/2)$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks for the answer. When I computed recursively, imputting new values of $h$ and the previously calculated $y$ value, it seems that the value $y_3$ is much closer to the solution at $t=2$ than $t_4$ is. The values I obtained where as follows: $y_1 = 0.7709$, $y_2 = 0.57791$, $y_3 = 0.44538$, and finally $y_4 = 0.35551$. Is it likely have made further mistakes? I used the Newton-Raphson method to solve each new cubic equation I obtained with the new $h$ and $y$ values each time.

Comment: I would check the arithmetics you are doing. I get $y_1=0.7709$, $y_2=0.6399$, $y_3=0.5546$ and $y_4=0.4942$. You can for example check that $0.7709 - 0.5\cdot 0.6399^3 = 0.6399$ so $y_2=0.6399$,.

Comment: "I obtained with the new $h$" What do you mean "new $h$". $h$ is fixed to $0.5$ right? You seem to have taken $h=0.5,1,1.5$ etc. This is not correct. btw once you have found a solution always check that its a correct solution by computing $|y_{n+1} - y_n + h y_{n+1}^3|$. This should be close to zero if you have found the solution.

Comment: @Winther Right, okay that was silly of me! I will fix that. Thank you again.